# Why Shrirama often referred as Raghava after Raghu when before and after Raghu many illustrious kings have emerged?

Tags: ramayana, rama, suryavansh

ShriRama was a purushottama. However he is linked only to Raghu, one of his ancestors but not Dilipa, Sagara, Ikshvaku, Bhagiratha, Aja, Dasharatha. Why Raghu is so important? Also after Rama, his sons are not referred as Raghus why?

Comment: Rama is also referred as Kakutstha(born in the lineage of king Kakuthstha). He is also called Ikshvaku kula tilaka(best among ikshvaku dynasty), Daasharathi(son of Dasharatha)  Lakshmana is also referred as Raghava. All the kings in the lineage can be referred as Raghavas. This might be seen in Raghuvamsha a kaavya by Kalidasa. As their stories are not popular, their references are also not known. Raghu did the VIshvajit mahayajna and lost all his wealth. But didn't undergo grief. He is well known for his faultless character and his charity. Who are illustrious kings after Rama?

Comment: Well Raama is called as Raaghava, as he is most famous Raaghava i.e. most famous descent of Raghu. And it is not that **only** he is called Raaghava. If you read Scriptures you will find others called Raaghava too.

Answer (score 2):

This question is related to [Describe the story of lunar race and solar race](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22516/describe-the-story-of-lunar-race-and-solar-race/22520#22520)

In most of the cases, the name of a lineage changes after a Chakravarti Samrat. However this is not a hard and fast rule, they can continue with old name as well.

Lord Shri Rama's lineage can be called as **Suryavanshi**, **Ikshvaku vanshi**, **Raghu vanshi or Raghav** etc. And Lord Shri Rama can be called as

> One who was born in the clan of  Surya (Sun God), **Suryavanshi Kshatriya**
>
> One who was born in the clan of  Ikshvaku, Ikshvaku vanshi
>
> One who was born in the clan of Mandhata, Mandhata vanshi
>
> One who was born in the clan of  Raghu, Raghu vanshi or **Raghav**
>
> Dashratha's son

Hence, Lord Shri Rama is mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana as Ikshvaku vanshi, Mandhata vanshi, Raghu vanshi or Raghava and Dasharatha's son.

Why most of the time Raghava (Raghuvanshi) or Dasharatha's son?

> Because Raghu was more recent Chakravarti king as compared to others in the lineage. And Dasharatha was his father.

**Note:** However, Valmiki Ramayana mention many kings in between Raghu and Dasharatha including Nahush and Yayati (who are Chandravanshi kings altogether as per other scriptures). Most of other sources tell only Aja in between Raghu and Dasharatha.

After Rama, this lineage had a name which was honored by the title Lord. So they followed Lord Shri Rama's name afterwards.

**Note:**

> Due to Raghu's name the lineage came to be known as Raghu vansh or Raghava. Not only Rama but whoever was born in the lineage after Raghu can be referred as Raghu vanshi or Raghava i.e. Aja, Dashratha, Laxmana and Bharat too can be referred as Raghava.

Same is the case with Arjuna. He can be called Chandra vanshi, Puru vanshi, Bharat vanshi or Bharata, Kuru vanshi or Kaurava, son of Pandu or Pandava, son of Pratha (birth name of Kunti) or Parth, son of Kunti or Kauntey.

But most of the time he is called as Parth or Pandav as compared to other names as these names are derrived from his immediate previous generations.