# How are the lunar race and solar race originated?

Tags: puranas, history, chandravansh, suryavansh

The solar race and lunar race story is popular among all puranas the solar race contains lord Rama and lunar race on other side lord Krishna . Is here someone who can describe the both side story, their kingdoms etc.

Comment: The story of Solar and Lunar Races is said in many Puranas.It took chapters in some Puranas. Adding it in the answers would be very long. The question becomes too broad.

Comment: @ Nog Shine not the whole stories but how to dynasties from sun and moon came to earth its special kings like king sagar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Solar and Lunar dynasties of **Vaivasvata Manavantra** (7th Manavantra) are given in

> Kurma Purana
>
> Brahma Purana
>
> Agni Purana
>
> Valmiki Ramayana
>
> Mahabharata
>
> some other Puranas too

**1. The Solar Dynasty (or Surya Vansh)**

Lord **Brahma**'s son was **Marichi**, Marichi's son **Kashyapa** and Kakshyapa's son **Vivasvana** (Sun god). Vivasvana's son was **Vaivasvata** (7th or current Manu).

Vaivasvata Manu had no children and he arranged for a sacrifice so that he might have a son. Nine sons were born as a result of this sacrifice. Their names were **Ikshvaku**, Nabhaga, Dhrishta, Sharyati, Narishyanta, Pramashu, Rishta, Karusha and Prishadhra. Manu also had a daughter named **Ila** (इला).

**Note:** Subsequently, thanks to a boon. Ila became a man named Sudyumna. Sudyumna's sons were Utkala, Gaya and Vinatashva. Utkala ruled in Orissa, Gaya in the region that is also called Gaya, and Vinatashva in the west. Or few sources say that earlier Sudyumna (i.e a man) was there but due to curse he became a woman (i.e Ila). When he/she was a woman she married Budha and gave birth to a son which is described in the later part of this answer.

**Popular kings of the Ikshvaku Vansh**

The complete list of the Ikshvaku Vansh is given in [Valmiki Ramayana - Bala Kanda - Sarga 70](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=1&language=dv&field_sarga_value=70). Few of them are as below:

> Vikukshi
>
> Kakutstha
>
> Sagar
>
> Bhagirath
>
> Raghu (After him, his lineage is called as **Raghavas**, hence, Lord Shri Rama is called as Raghav.)
>
> Dasaratha
>
> Lord Shri Rama

**Note:** Valmiki Ramayana mention many kings in between Raghu and Aja including Nahusha and Yayati (who are mentioned in Lunar Dynasty too). But there should not be any doubt as names can be duplicate. However, other sources doesn't depict any king between Raghu and Aja.

**2. The Lunar Dynasty (or Chandra or Soma Vansh)**

Lord **Brahma** also had a son named **Atri** and Atri had a son named **Soma** or Chandra (Moon god).

Soma performed a rajasuya yajna (royal sacrifice). Having performed the sacrifice, Soma became the ruler of all the worlds. This made him very arrogant and he abducted the sage Brihaspati's wife Tara. This led to a terrible war between the devas and the asuras (*the fifth war between the devas and the asuras took place over the abduction of Tara and this came to be known as the Tarakamaya war*). Tara was eventually restored to Brihaspati, but Soma and Tara had a son named **Budha**.

Budha married Ila (daughter of Vaivasvata Manu) and they had a son named **Pururava**. In that lineage then born kings like **Nahusha** and **Yayati**. Yayati and Devayani had two sons, **Yadu** and Tursavu. Yayati and Sharmishtha had three sons, Druhya, Anu and **Puru**.

Yadu's descendants came to be known as the **Yadavas**.

Puru's descendants came to be known as the **Pauravas**.

**Popular kings of Yadavas**

> Haihaya
>
> Kritavirya
>
> Kartavirya Arjuna (He is also known as **ShashtrAjuna** and was the most skilled of fighters. His greatest deeds were his defeat and **imprisonment of Ravana, king of Lanka**. He eventually met his death at the hands of **Lord Parashurama**.)
>
> Madhu (After him, his lineage is called as **Madhavas**. Hence, Lord Krishna is called as Madhav.)
>
> Vrishni (After him, his lineage is called as **Vrishneyas**. Hence, Lord Krishna is called as Vrisney. His name is mentioned in **Bhagavad Gita 10.37**.)
>
> Lord Shri Krishna

**Popular kings of Pauravas**

> Bharat (After him, his lineage is called as **Bharat Vansh**. His name is mentioned in **Bhagavad Gita 4.7**.)
>
> Hasthi
>
> Kuru (After him, his lineage is called as **Kauravas**.)
>
> Pandu (After him, his lineage is called as **Pandavas**.)
>
> Dhritarashtra
>
> Yudhistira

**Note:** Our country's name **Bharat Varsh (the region of Bharat)** is said to be after king Bharat's name. But other than above mentioned Bharat, many kings were born earlier whose names were Bharat. One of them was king Bharat who was born in 1st Manavantra in the lineage of Priyvrata (the son of Svayambhu Manu). His name is not given here as these lineage are given from Vaivasvata Manavantra (7th Manavantra).

---

**EDIT [to answer SHebbar@'s follow up Qs]**

> which Purana say that Budha married Ila? Mahabharata says Ila was both father and mother of Pururavas.

Even Mahabharata say that Ila married Budha / Vudha:

> Ila will have **Vudha for her husband**, and from Vudha will spring Pururavas. From Pururavas will spring Ayu. From Ayu will spring Nahusha, and Nahusha will beget a son named Yayati. ~ [Mahabharata: Anusasana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b112.htm)

> Atri had for [his] son Soma. Soma's son was called Vudha. Vudha had one son, of the splendour of the great Indra, called Pururavas. Pururavas had a son called Ayus. Ayus had for his son Nahusha. Nahusha had for his son Yayati who was a royal sage equal to a celestial. ~ [Mahabharata, Book 7: Drona Parva: Jayadratha-Vadha Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07140.htm)

More details can be found in **Vishnu Purana: Part 4: Chapter 1 & 6**. The answer [Why is Nahusha's last name Manava?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4143/why-is-nahushas-last-name-manava/23419#23419) explais from **Vishnu Purana: Part 4: Chapter 1** regarding how Purúravas was born. [Vishnu Purana: Part 4: Chapter 6](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp098.htm) explais how Budha was born.

Comment: @YDSvery good and elaborated answer. very nice.;)

Comment: may i know the refrence to the footnote story that would be more good.;)

Comment: @Fiercelord It is from the chapter 'The Lunar Dynasty' of Kurma Purana. Updated in answer too.

Comment: while it does make sense that people shouldn't 'fight' over who is greater, you don't *need* to resort to saying that Shiva is equal to Vishnu, just to bring peace between the factions. If you really believe it, that's fine. Vishnu alone is paramatma. Others may say otherwise. But the difference in opinion need not lead to a fight. We should not bring down the ideal just because we cannot reach it, or because it might offend people.

Comment: @ram It's directly taken from Kurma Purana. Pls see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23882/12304 for more details... anyway I hv removed it from here...

Comment: @yds which Purana say that Budha married Ila?

Comment: Mahabharata says Ila was both father and mother of Pururavas. Ila was born as girl but changed to boy but remained girl after entering a territory (I heard this somewhere from bhagavatam but can't remember now) @yds

Comment: @SHebbar https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23419/12304 answers ur Qs..updated this answer too..